# Strange syntax in macro definition [C]

Tags: c, macros, driver

I'm new to C, and currently reading through driver code that I have to alter.  I came across a wall of text with lines like:

```
#define IOCTL_AIO                           ('i'<<8)
#define AIO_IOCTL_REG_READ                  (IOCTL_AIO|0)
#define AIO_IOCTL_REG_WRITE                 (IOCTL_AIO|1)
...
```

I understand that these are being used for macros, but I don't understand the syntax of `(IOCTL|0)`.  These macros are being used in `switch:case`'s later on, if that changes anything.

Would someone explain what exactly the syntax `(IOCTL_AIO|0)` would mean?

Thanks!

Comment: It is indeed meaningless. Where did you get those macros from?

Comment: @barak manos They're from a Solaris driver that I have to adapt to Linux commands;  I ran the driver & test application, so they do actually work—I'm just not sure how.

Comment: By "meaningless" I meant that the `|0` has no effect, not that the macro doesn't work. That is what you're asking about, isn't it?

Comment: Maybe it's just to make the code consistent with itself, i.e. to be consistent means a lot, and this is something I often do, it doesn't matter anyway because it has no effect at all, so it makes it readable and itention clear, and doesn't affect the program.

Comment: `IOCTL_AIO` is the base command, and then subcommands are given as `|0`, `|1`, `|2`, `|3`. Curious, but not that strange for driver code.

Comment: `|0` could theoretically expand the type of an expression from 8 or 16 bits to 32 bits, but it doesn't seem to be the purpose in this case.

Comment: `|0` is just for consistency with others, as @iharob pointed out.

Comment: @mtijanic That base/sub command explanation makes sense based on the format of the rest of the driver.  I definitely agree that it would make more sense (to me) if they just provided the sub-command.

Answer (score 3):

```
#define AIO_IOCTL_REG_READ                  (IOCTL_AIO|0)
```

is same as

```
#define AIO_IOCTL_REG_READ                  IOCTL_AIO
```

I suspect the first form is used to make it visually consistent with the macro(s) that follow it.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for your help!  While the `(Command|Subcommand)` format made sense to me, it ended up not being exactly true to what I thought.

I did a little testing with the format of:

```
int i = ( # | # );
printf("%i", i);
```

After seeing the output of this setup I looked a little further, and found out what was happening; the two numbers are being handled with binary arithmetic, namely the bitwise OR.

This takes two inputs, A and B, and outputs C.  For example:

```
A = 100101101
B = 010001000
---------------
C = 110101101
```

It takes each bit for A and B, and performs an OR to get the output bit for C.

This is what is actually happening:

```
AIO_IOCTL [26880] = 110100100000000 
Command      [31] =           11111
----------------------------------- 
Macro     [26911] = 110100100011111
```

Edit:
Re-worded the intro, @mtijanic pointed out it seemed to be contradictory to what I had meant.

Comment: Please read about operators in C if you don't know what C operators like `|`, `&`, `^`, `,`, or `~` are doing.

Comment: Which actually is `(command|subcommand)`. Or `device|command` or whatever. The first one, `AIO_IOCTL` or `'i'<<8` specifies the base value that will be emitted. This could be a base command, a register address or anything else. The second one says which command to perform, in this case read or write.

Comment: @mtijanic You're absolutely right.  I was under the impression that it was behaving in some other way when I read your original comment, so I wanted to add this in case it would be helpful to someone else.